# Maximal cardinality of a set of pairwise independent variables all dependent with another variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence, bayes-theorem

I suppose that I have a multinomial random variables $V$ with $n$ states and a set of $m$ boolean variables $B_i$.

The graphical representation of the system is a naive bayesian network with $V$ at the center and a set of variables  $B_i$ having $V$ as unique parent.

This graphical representations implies the conditional independences : $\forall i \lt j , I(B_i,B_j | V)$ i.e. knowing V, $B_i$ and $B_j$ are independent.

The probabiliy distribution is fully described by the marginal probability of $V$ and  by the conditional probabilities $P(B_i/V)$

I also want my system to verify independence property between every pair of $B_i$ (those independence are not implied by the graphical representation of my Bayesian network).

So, to sum it up, I have :

$\forall i \lt j ,  I(B_i,B_j)$

$\forall i \lt j , I(B_i,B_j | V)$

$\forall i , \lnot I(B_i,V)$

My question is  : how many $B_i$ can we have depending on n ?

My idea is that mutual independence provides constraints for each pair $(i,j)$. There are $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ such pairs where m is the size of the $B_i$ set. The dimension of all the conditional probability matrices is $m.n$. So the number of constraints grows faster with $m$ than the dimension. So it seems that m should be limited. Anyway that is far from being a rigorous demonstration.

for $n=2$ it is not possible to have two variables $B_1$ and $B_2$. Knowing $B_1$ modifies the probability for $V$ that, in turn, modify that of $B_2$. So $B_1$ and $B_2$ can not be independent.

But for $n \ge 3$, can $m$ be infinite and, otherwise, what would be its maximum ?

Comment: It depends on how dependent on $V$ they need to be. If you have $m$ independent binary $B_i$, then there must be at least $2^m$ different states the system can be in. If the value of $V$ completely the determines the values of the $B_i$ then they constitute a system containing the $B_i$ and having exactly $n$ states, Thus it must be that $2^m \le n$. But if the value of $V$ merely influences the probabilities for the $B_i$, then more states than $n$ can exist, and $m$ has no maximum. Not even for $n=2$, because a modification of $P(V)$ need not always modify $P(B_2)$.

Comment: As an example, let $B_i\in\{0, 1\}, V = \max \{B_1, B_2\}$. Knowing $B_1$ changes the probabilities of $V$ but does not influence the probabilities for $B_2$.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I was speaking of strict independence $P(B_1=i,B_2=j)=P(B_1=i).P(B_2=j)$. Anyway, I need to add an important information for my question to be interesting. The $B_i$ should be independent from each other given $V$. So the system is described as the probability of $V$ and the conditional properties $P(B_i/V)$. Its graphical representation is a naive Bayesian network. I will reedit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: So am I talking about strict independence of the $B_i$  It is the *dependence* on $V$ that I am referring to.

Comment: I have reedited the question so it is clearer. By the way, just before you add your comment, I found an important element that can help answer the question. Seeing my question had not suscited reactions (probably in part because it was not well formulated), I was intending to just add a remark inviting people interested in the answer to ask me.